# Bare-metal recovery on dissimilar hardware [Win/Linux]?

Tags: backup, disaster-recovery

I'm planning a disaster recovery for our servers, and have been looking at this solution. I know of Clonezilla, but it does not entirely comply to the "different hardware" part.

I could still probably use Clonezilla with some workarounds, but does a better solution exist, with a straightforward recovery process? 
Or is Virtualization a much better idea?

(I have small and simple servers)

Comment: Shopping questions are not allowed.  But either Virtualization or shadow protect is what you should look into.  Shadow protect can restore to dissimilar hardware and it works well I've tried it.

Answer (score 1):

Foreman + Puppet for me. Can trash the server any moment and after 40 minutes the same server is up and running on new hardware pretty much. Not fairy for everything, but can do a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably see the most benefit from using Virtualisation, especially with something like OpenVZ for the cookie-cutter Linux servers, and KVM for the windows ones.  Proxmox 2.0 is worth a look, as this supports both OpenVZ and KVM under the same management controller.

Then use something like Puppet or Chef on top, for more customisation after the server has been provisioned.